# Couldn't find a project to run. Ensure a project exists in D:\home\site\wwwroot

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, kudu

I've been wrestling with this issue forever now. I'm trying to get my ASP.NET Core 2.1 app to run on Azure App Service.

Here's the strange behavior I'm seeing in Kudu.

I see the `dll` file for my project in Kudu console in `D:\home\site\wwwroot`. I then type `dotnet run myproject.dll` and I get the following error:

> Couldn't find a project to run. Ensure a project exists in
>   D:\home\site\wwwroot

Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run?tabs=netcore2x)

> The dotnet run command is used in the context of projects, not built
>   assemblies. If you're trying to run a framework-dependent application
>   DLL instead, you must use dotnet without a command.

So try and run it like this

```
dotnet myproject.dll
```

Comment: thank you very much.. I was 2 hours scratching my head over this...

Answer (score 29):

I was having the same issue. Not sure if this is a work-around but it ran the code.

```sh
dotnet run --project name-of-your-project-here
```

Comment: Or if you're in the project folder simply, dotnet run

Comment: can i run a soultion

Answer (score 7):

The solution consists of one or several projects, and the`dotnet`command is used in the context of projects, hence: you need first to change the directory to the project folder then run the command:

```
cd ProjectName
dotnet run       // or even "dotnet add package <Package Name>"
```

Answer (score 4):

Go to the path of your dll and run it using the following command:

```
dotnet yourprojectname.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of MacBook, it is the same way as well, for example:

```
dotnet ../../bin/Debug/net7.0/yourprojectname.dll
```